# Creating different margins on the first page of a word template

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, templates, margins

I have a letterhead template and I need the first page left margin to be larger than subsequent pages.

I've seen the option of placing a text box or image box in the header to push the text but this ends up throwing off the tabs and bullet list indentation markers.

I thought of setting up the first page using two columns and pushing the text to start on the second column but I can't seem to find a way to get the text to switch back to 1 column on the second page when it is created from text overflowing.

Does anyone know how something like this is possible?

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: I would highly suggest just to use a section break and change the margins for the first and other pages manually.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I don't think this would work though since I want this to be a template that can be distributed to the rest of my company without anyone having to play with the margins manually.

Comment: You could set up the two sections in the template with the margins already set? This seems better to me than adding a textbox.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I thought that would be the best solution but I don't know how to setup my template so that when a second page is added it is setup as the separate section. I want the template to open as a single page and when someone types more text then will fit on the page, it will flow into the second page with the new section already set. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think that is possible without the use of macros, however I think I found something useful, please see my answer.

Comment: See my reply below. In Word, you do NOT want to change the "margins" but rather the area in which text can be typed. It seems like the same thing, but it is not.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but it came up in my results as I was searching for the answer.

What you need to do is click somewhere on the template where you want the new margins to start to apply, insert a **continuous** section break, click somewhere below that continuous section break, go to your custom margin settings, and select apply to "this section."

This is a little better than the "after this point" option, because that option inserts a page break section break, which does not work for the OP, because they wanted to keep their template one page long. By inserting a continuous section break instead, you can keep the one-page template and new margins will automatically apply when the user reaches their second page.

[image: Screenshot of margin settings]

Comment: Not sure if you're aware, but it is considered rude to rollback another user's edit just to basically repeat the same edit yourself. If you want to change back a small part of the first edit, just make an edit on top of the previous one,

Comment: Sorry robinCTS, I didn't know I could edit out your grammar error after I accepted. I'm a new user, which is also why I don't have enough "rep" to directly embed the screenshot myself. Thanks for the tip, that's good to know!

Comment: That's alright. I figured it was just because you're a newbie ;-) I'm a little puzzled though. What grammar error? I can't see one in the revision history. PS Now you *can* embed screenshots yourself ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to keep the punctuation inside of the quotation marks at the end of the second paragraph.

Comment: Well, if that's what you want, then I'm not going to get into an editing war with you over it ;-) However, I do *strenuously* object to to you calling that my "grammar error" ;-) Seriously though (no, just kidding, this is all light-hearted), if you're up for some pedantry, my edit wasn't a grammatical error because 1) The text you're quoting doesn't contain a period so no period should be inside the quotes; 2) Therefore there needs to be a period at the end of the sentence, *outside* of the quotes. …

Comment: … If you are implying that my edit was incorrect because I didn't use "Typesetter's Quotes", then all I can say is, that is an American (illogical) style based on a purely historical mechanical reason, not a linguistic reason and should have been thrown out when mechanical typesetters were thrown out. :-P (The good new is that it  *is* going out of fashion, albeit slowly.)

Answer (score 1):

To create a different margins on the first page, go to page setup, click the layout tab, click different first page. I have to do this every year to edit our stationery, and have to look it up each time. Maybe now I'll remember.[screenshot showing the different first page menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkkZP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this in a different way and I think you can achieve this using a different first page header. Refer to [this](http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/differentmargins.htm) article which gives detailed steps on how the header can be used to create different margins.

Comment: Nope, I've been through this and it works for the top margin but I still can't adjust the left margin and have it different on the first page compared to the others, thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Paul, It's working for me. You need to create a textbox and set wrapping to square. I have [uploaded](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4h-y94oB7DOOTVXTnhxbjRjNDg/edit?usp=sharing) a sample document for you to look at (click File -> Download).

Comment: Thanks Adam, I know this way works but the problem we face with this is that the tabs in bullet lists become awkward to work with. I was hoping there was a way to achieve different margins without faking them. Thanks.

Comment: @Paul, I understand the plight, however margins are based on section formatting so other than this work around I don't believe there is any other way to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Word 2010+ has the ability to set margins "from this point forward"

1. set your margins generally
2. set custom margins on the second page, with "from this point forward" selected.

[image]

Comment: All this does is insert a Section Break without telling the user that it’s inserting a Section Break.  The OP has considered Section Breaks and discussed why they are not a solution for his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've worked it out, but I have found that when trying to make the header (or footer) different to the previous page, the only way to stop it affecting the first page (because ticking "different first page" didn't work), I noticed that if you deselect the "Link to Previous" option in the Navigation field to the right of the Options section in the Design ribbon, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

## Here's a super easy way.

1. Insert a **Section Break (Next Page)** from **Page Layout > Breaks**
2. Click on the page you want to expand/narrow the margins.
3. Click on **Custom Margins** from **Page Layout > Margins**
4. In the Page Setup window put in the custom margin size you want then click **OK**.

[image: Custom Margins with Section Break Next Page]

## Here's a super hard way.

Which requires your letter head to be a macro enabled workbook.

1. Setup your first page how you want it with the correct margins.
2. Create a macro with the below code:

**Code:**

```
Sub Document_Open()
    If ActiveDocument.Sections.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.Start, End:=Selection.Start). _
        InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Selection.Start = Selection.Start + 1

    With ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.Start, End:=ActiveDocument. _
        Content.End).PageSetup
        .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.54) 'CHANGE THIS it's margin of new pages!
        .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
    End With

    Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), _
    Name:="CheckPages"


End Sub

Sub CheckPages()
    Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), _
    Name:="CheckPages"

    If ActiveDocument.Sections.Count = 1 Then
    ActiveDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(5.54)'CHANGE THIS it's margin of first page!
    End If

End Sub
```

3. Save your document.

Answer (score 0):

### No - No - No

### No different section! Instead use the First-Page Header to change where you can type on the page!

Instead, you place a frame or a textbox in the First-Page Header, to simulate a Margin.

There are tried and true methods of setting up letterhead in Word. Here are two web pages on this:

- [Setting Up Letter Templates](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/LetterheadRibbon.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- [How can I get a Different Header/Footer or the Second Page](http://addbalance.com/word/headersfooters.htm#2007-2013) *(my page)*

You do not want to be changing the margins because this requires a section break. People using the template will delete that break or continue typing on the first page meaning that the section break will move. Instead, put a Frame or a TextBox in the First-Page-Header (or Footer) that moves text to the right or left (or up or down). The textbox/frame can contain names, etc., or be blank and borderless. The key is that text typed in the body will not overtype it so it acts as a margin.

Here is a screenshot showing page 1 and 2. **Both have identical "margins!"** The black text shows where text can be typed in the body of the document. Pages 1 and 2 appear to have very different margin settings. They do not.

[image: screenshot]

If you like, you can look at samples from my website's download page and use them out of the box or use them as examples. [Letterhead Styles and Textboxes Tutorial](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#LetterheadTextboxesAndStylesTutorial)