# Printing on colored letterhead with black and white printer

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2016

I have colored letterheads with header and footer in word format and also the same word document in physical printed page.

I want to feed the colored letterhead to the black and white printer and print on letterhead.

For that I'll have to exactly align my text with header and footer otherwise it will overlap on header footer.

How can I make exact measurements in microsoft word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can set the top and bottom margins of a page numerically.**

In the "Layout" menu, choose "Margins"->"Custom Margins..." to get the dialog as illustrated below where you can enter the dimensions you need:

[image]

If you only use the letterhead paper for the first page then [Creating different margins on the first page of a word template](https://superuser.com/q/612945/272824) may be of use to you.

**To get the values to enter into the boxes, you have two options:**

- As you're going to be using the ready-printed letterhead paper, I suggest using a ruler to measure the margins.
- You could open the colored letterheads with header and footer in word format and use the ruler ("View" menu, select "Print layout", then check the "Ruler" setting) to measure, but using a physical ruler on the actual paper is probably faster and easier, especially as you may want to make slight adjustments for visual appearance.